# Tips on optimizing SQL text search

Tags: sql-server

I am building a SQL query that will search a table (of email data) on two fields [Subject] and [Body]. What I need to find are records that detail out events that occurred after a layoff from work. The emails will usually include the key words "post" and "termination" to signal a record relevant to my search. These key words may show up in a phrase where they are combined, but they may also be written in different ways. (post-termination, post term,....). These combinations may show up in the [Subject] or [Body] field, and sometimes both.

My problem is false positives. I am getting a bunch of records that aren't relevant.

My query so far goes like this...

```
 WHERE [Subject] like '%post%' and [Subject] like '%termination%'
```

OR

```
   [Body] like '%post%' and [Body] like '%termination%'
```

I've included more lines for the combinations I have listed above.

Any hints on balancing my query so that I maximize the retrieval of relevant records while minimizing the amount of false positives? Any help would be much appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: the [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag should use ISO/IEC standard SQL **only**, this SQL code seams to be "SQL Server" syntax

Comment: A basic text search like this isn't going to get what you're looking for. You need to get more specific with your search strings (look for `post` surrounded by spaces for example) or use an indexing/search platform that can do more semantic searches. Be advised that leading wildcard queries like these will do a full table scan every time, so as your table grows, performance will degrade.

Comment: Please show some sample data of a “false positive”, and your full query

Answer (score 0):

May be (if your words are always in the same order):

```
WHERE [Subject] like '%post%term%' OR [Body] like '%post%term%'
```